# How to create a form in PHP/MySQL to add allowed IPs to the website?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm looking for some help and advice, and can't seem to find an answer.

I have a website, that I want to be completely blocked off from everyone, besides a few that I allow to use the website.

I was wondering if there is a way to make a table/form on my website to add the specified IP to an allow list?

I currently use this, but I find it's not very effective as I have to change the actual file manually to add the IP each time.

```
<?php
$allowlist = array(
    '00.000.000.000' /* Example */
);

if(!in_array($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'],$allowlist)){
    die('This website cannot be accessed from your location.');
}
?>
```

Any help of advice would be greatly appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: ip!=person, why not put in a 'proper' user authentication system

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you probably want a database system like MySQL, and you *probably* want user accounts (username/password pairs) rather than IPs, since IPs do not represent *people per se*.

Edit: Well, you already have MySQL in your title, so, yeah, MySQL is a solution here.